# Hiding a div when scrolling and showing it on mouseover

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I would like to show the header in the top of my page, and hide it when scrolled, like [this site](http://divide.comyr.com/divide_by_two.html); And I would also like to show the header on `mouseover`. But I'm a designer, not a programmer, and am struggling to get it to work.

The code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#header').mouseover( function() {
        $(this).find('.action').show();
    });
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
        $('#header').fadeOut();
    } else {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#header').fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is, there is no way to trigger the mouseover event when the header is not displayed. Maybe you could add a small box in the top that would allow you to hover over it and bring back the header.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler Ah, a div that would cover the same space as the header, maybe with a transparent background? How can I call the header  back from hovering a diferent div? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can play with the opacity of the header.
Here is a working example, using your template : [**demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6URKw/embedded/result/)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var header, op = 1;

$(function(){
    header = $("#header");
    header.hover(
        function(){ $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1); },
        function(){ if (!op) $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0); }
    );
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600 && op == 1) {
        header.fadeTo("slow", 0);
        op = 0;
    } else {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 600 && op == 0) {
            header.fadeTo("slow", 1);
            op = 1;              
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like the perfect solution, but I cant get it to work!

Comment: @user1612807 check it out, that should be good (my example was wrong, sorry) : http://jsfiddle.net/6URKw/

Answer (score 0):

Create a transparent fake div exatly on top of the header div and set default display=hidden.
Then simply show it whenever you hide the header. That way you the mourseover effect will work. Also hide the div when the header is display, else you wont be able to click on the links in the header.

Here is the code sample

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#transparent_div').mouseover( function() {
         $('#header').fadeIn();
    });
    $('#transparent_div').mouseleave( function() {
         $('#header').fadeOut();
    });

});
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
    $('#transparent_div').show();
        $('#header').fadeOut();
    } else {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#transparent_div').hide();
            $('#header').fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost working but I'm still having problems in clicking the links when the header comes back. You can check it out here [link](http://divide.comyr.com/divide_by_two.html). Any suggestions?